How to add objects to RealityKit scene programmatically?
I have a scene loading from a resource in a RealityView on visionOS. It displays correctly. I want to add additional objects programmatically and I'm trying;
var body: some View {
    RealityView { content in
        if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
            viewModel.rootEntity = scene
            content.add(scene)

            var anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(world: [25, 0, -0.5])  
            let sphere = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 20.0)
            let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, roughness: 0.5, isMetallic: true)
            let modelEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: sphere, materials: [material])
            anchorEntity.addChild(modelEntity)
            content.add(modelEntity)
        }
    }
}

However, the sphere never appears. The code runs without error.

In info.plist, turn Immersive Space Application Session Role On (and change the code in the YourApp.swift file) and you'll immediately see your huge sphere with 20 meters radius. Also, why do you need an anchor with 25 meter offset if you're not adding it to the scene?
content.add(anchorEntity)

By default RealityKit doesn't render the inner surface of 3D objects, only the outer one. Without anchor you don’t see the sphere because its diameter is 40 meters.

Thank you. I changed the anchor entity position to [0,0,-.5] and the radius to 0.5. My pList has Preferred Default Scene Session Role = (string)Volumetric Application Session Role, Scene Configuration is a Dictionary with 1 entry, Immersive Space Application Role (array) with 1 entry, Initial Immersions Style = (string) Mixed Immersion. But nothing appears. Also, my app also has an immersive scene also created with reality pro. I can switch to immersive view and the scene also renders correctly there, but adding content there doesn't appear either.

If your starting scene should appear in a volumetric window, then make this window larger using the .defaultSize(width: 2, height: 2, depth: 2, in: .meters) modifier. And hide the default RCP sphere for a while.

P. S. You'll not see your sphere if it's outside the volumetric window.

All you have to do is to replace the last line of code in your code snippet with the line from my answer.

The model must be attached to the anchor, and the anchor must be attached to the content object.

Thanks for your patience and help, it's very much appreciated. I did fix the scale problems, the default window etc. However, the Entities won't appear unless I also do a setParent on the anchor. I've gone back and forth testing both ways now twice. I'll keep testing.

The answer turns out to be that you have to set the parent of the anchor and the new entity to the scene.
adding;
modelEntity.setParent(scene)
anchorEntity.setParent(scene)

will display the new mesh correctly.

John, did you read my answer carefully?  What you wrote in your answer is  almost the same as in your question. Now you attach your sphere to the sphere from the RCP scene and the anchor is empty again.
